# Pretty print XML from NSString in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

I have an XML document in an NSString object in Objective-C.

The XML is obtained from a web service, and it doesn't have any formatting, line breaks or indentation.

Can anyone tell me the easiest way to produce a new NSString object, which has the XML formatted nicely, with each element on a new line with proper indentation etc?

Comment: You'd have to parse the XML into a DOM and "print" that DOM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay so I solved this myself.

This uses Google's GData XML parsing wrapper around the built-in `/usr/include/libxml2` XML library, to convert an `NSString` containing unformatted XML, into another `NSString` which is nicely formatted, with indentation and line breaks.

Note this is based on Xcode 5, and the target is iOS 7; although it might work for other targets too.

---

**Step 1. Copy GData classes (source) into the project**

Copy 2 source files, `GDataXMLNode.h` and `GDataXMLNode.m`, from the [GData library](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FSource%2FXMLSupport) directly into the project.

---

**Step 2. Add libxml2 to the search path**

In Project -> Build Settings -> Search Paths -> Header Search Paths, add path: `/usr/include/libxml2`

In Project -> Build Settings -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags, add flag: `-lxml2`

---

**Step 3. If your app uses ARC, disable ARC for the GData class**

In Targets -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> `GDataXMLNode.m`, add Compiler Flag: `-fno-objc-arc`

*At this point, make sure your project builds. If it does, GData is configured correctly.*

---

**Step 4. Edit `GDataXMLNode.m` to make it pretty-print XML by default**

Open `GDataXMLNode.m`, and find method `- (NSString *)XMLString`

Change: `int format = 0;`

To: `int format = 1;`

---

**Step 5. Add the following method anywhere in your project**

`#import "GDataXMLNode.h"`

```
+ (NSString *)prettyPrintXML:(NSString *)rawXML {
    NSError *error;
    GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:rawXML options:0 error:&error];
    return error ? rawXML : doc.rootElement.XMLString;
}
```

---

*That's it, this method will convert a raw XML string into a nicely formatted string.*

Answer (score 8):

In case you don't want to include GData in your project, use this method:

```
+ (NSString *)prettyPrintXML:(NSString *)rawXML {
    const char *utf8Str = [rawXML UTF8String];
    xmlDocPtr doc = xmlReadMemory(utf8Str, (int)strlen(utf8Str), NULL, NULL, XML_PARSE_NOCDATA | XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS);
    xmlNodePtr root = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);
    xmlNodePtr xmlNode = xmlCopyNode(root, 1);
    xmlFreeDoc(doc);

    NSString *str = nil;

    xmlBufferPtr buff = xmlBufferCreate();
    doc = NULL;
    int level = 0;
    int format = 1;

    int result = xmlNodeDump(buff, doc, xmlNode, level, format);

    if (result > -1) {
        str = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:(xmlBufferContent(buff))
                                       length:(NSUInteger)(xmlBufferLength(buff))
                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }
    xmlBufferFree(buff);

    NSCharacterSet *ws = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
    NSString *trimmed = [str stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:ws];
    return trimmed;
}
```

It's adaptated from GData's `init` and `XMLString` methods, stripping error checks to keep it short. Please remember to include them as you need.

This way you just have to include libxml2 to your search path (that's step 2 in previous answer) and `#import <libxml/tree.h>` to format XML in Objective-C.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! The code is in production now but I'd definitely try this approach next time.